# ¿Se puede hacer un array infinito de Strings?

Tags: java, nodos

¿Se puede hacer un array infinito de *Strings*?

Estoy intentando hacer una serie de N terminos *(a, ab, abc, abcd, a1, ab1,abc1,abcd1,a2,ab2,abc2,abcd2,a3,....)*.

Lo sé hacer con `String[]e=new String[25];`, pero, ¿Cómo lo hago infinito?

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante realizar preguntas en base a el documento [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), **te sugerimos editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que has tratado o investigado**. No olvides realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Buen día. En **Java** no es posible crear arreglos con tamaño infinito.

```
final int TAM = 100;
String[] cadenas = new String[TAM];
cadena[0] = "Hola";
//...
cadena[99] = "Ciao";
for(int c= 0 ; c < cadenas.length; c++){
   //..
}
```

En este ejemplo definimos un arreglo de `String` con un tamaño específico de 100. Si yo quisiera aumentar ese tamaño, no podría. El mismo compilador indicaría un error al tratar de cambiar su tamaño.

Tal vez tu opción sería usar un [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Te dejo el link para que revises la documentación oficial.

Answer (score 1):

Si con N te refieres a un número que introduce el usuario, es tan fácil como hacer esto:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int tamanyo = sc.nextInt();
String[] array = new String[tamanyo];
```

La otra opción como te comentan es usar ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Para esos casos en los que necesitas que puedas ir agregando nuevos datos del mismo tipo existe **"List"** (Lista), su uso es sencillo y eficiente, para ello usas el código:

```
List<nombredetipo> nombredelalista = new ArrayList<nombredetipo>();
```

- Si quieres agregar un elemento del mismo tipo a esa lista, debes usar:
- `nombredelalista.add(nombredelavariable)`

**El código de ejemplo quedaría así**

```
List<String> nombres = new ArrayList<String>();

nombres.add("Juan");
```

Answer (score -1):

Primero, puedes compartir más de tu código y editar la pregunta?

Se sabe cómo recibirás dichos términos? Como ya han dicho, tu mejor opción aquí es usar una `List`, que es la interfaz, pero cuya implementación específica debiera ser, por simplicidad, `ArrayList`. Suponiendo que puedes ir iterando sobre tu entrada, quizás tu código luzca algo así

```
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 String line = "";
 do  {
     line = scanner.nextLine();
     list.add(line);
 } while (!line.equals(""));

 System.out.println(list);
```

En dicho caso, no sabes a priori cual es el tamaño de tu List, lo cual debiera ser más que suficiente para resolver tu problema. En cualquier caso, la documentación oficial de List la encuentras [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) donde también encontrarás las posibles implementaciones

Técnicamente es "infinito"

Comment: Esta línea de código es incorrecta:`for(String str: scanner.nextLine())`. Dará error de compilación. Si se quiere recorrer una lista de objetos para añadir objetos de tipo `string`, se lo debería de hacer con un `for`normal: `for(int i=0;i != 10;++i)` y adentro del bucle se agregaría el método `nextLine()`.

Comment: Amigo, es una sugerencia, no esperaba ser 100% preciso, por algo dice "algo así". Edito mi respuesta de hace 2 años